# MS-Access - MailMerge specific record from a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating an Access 2019 database for small family business (dog breeding) so I setup some tables containing all details on the dogs and the owners. Just to give an idea (simplistic description of the situation):

```
Dogs
    Name
    Birth
    Microchip
    Etc…
```

```
Owners
    Name
    Address
    Etc…
```

I was now trying to create a "Contract composer" for when we sell the dogs. So I made a new table "Contract" and a related form

```
Contract
    Seller ->linked to Owners table
    Buyer ->linked to Owners table
    Dog ->linked to Dogs table
    Price
```

And made a query to pull all relevant information from the related tables so that I can have

```
ContractQuery
    Seller!Name
    Seller!Address
    Buyer!Name
    Buyer!Address
    Dog!Name
    Dog!Birthdate
    Dog!Microchip
    Contract!Price
```

Everything so far is working perfectly fine.
Now I need to convert the ContractQuery fields in a form of "human readable" contract. I think the best way to do so is the MailMerge to a specific Word document, and I've already setup one. My problem is: how can I set a button into the Contract form so that the "contract.doc" is populated with the specific record I'm seeing now in the form?
I had made some researches and the most relevant information I've found is this
https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/run-mail-merge-from-vba.158126/
and this https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3237
But they are related to old MS-Access so when I tried to apply it I had errors all around. Unluckily my VBA knowledge is far from being proficient and I was not able to make it work.
Can anyone help me, or address me to a solution?
Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Try to implement this example and post your code if you get stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392840/generating-completed-pdf-forms-using-word-docs-and-ms-access/62393395#62393395

Comment: OK using that code I was able to get some rusults. Now I have my nice PDF document BUT it is only for the last record of my query (I imagine that what happens is that the scripts loops through all the records, saves a .pdf for each overwriting the previous every time. This is anyway a HUGE step ahead. Unless you have some hints on this matter, I think I'll work to have the query linked to the form so that it will only have one single record inside :)

Comment: Cant really tell unless you post the code - check the file name for each record in the loop is unique.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks for pointing me at the good direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got it working thanks to Kostas K, pointing me in the fight direction. This is my final code, it might need some cleanup and tweaking (for example, the loop within the resulst is now redundant as I only have one result), but it is working :)

The solution is based on this post, should anyone need please have a look at it as reference for the template docx etc

[Generating completed PDF forms using word docs and ms access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392840/generating-completed-pdf-forms-using-word-docs-and-ms-access/62393395#62393395)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdMergeIt_Click()
On Error GoTo Trap
    ' **** defining project path as string to make this portable
    Dim CurPath As String
    CurPath = CurrentProject.path & "\"
    ' MsgBox (CurPath) 'debug

    Dim TEMPLATE_PATH As String
    TEMPLATE_PATH = CurPath & "Contratto.dotx"

    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim idx As Long
    ' *** intercepting the contract ID field from the launching form
    Dim checkID As String
    checkID = ID.Value
    'MsgBox (checkID) 'debug
    
    ' **** defining a SQL query on my Access query
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "Select * from qContratto where ID =" & checkID & ""
    ' MsgBox (strSQL) 'debug
       

    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    wApp.Visible = False
    ' ***** changed the OpenRecordset to call my strSQL query insetad than reading the whole Access query
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    If rs.EOF Then GoTo Leave

    With rs
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
    End With

    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add(TEMPLATE_PATH)
        With wDoc
            .Bookmarks("Prezzo").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Prezzo, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("Venditore").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Venditore, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("Acquirente").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Acquirente, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("Cessione").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Cessione, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("NomeCane").Range.Text = Nz(rs!NomeCane, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("Riproduzione").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Riproduzione, vbNullString)
            .Bookmarks("Sesso").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Sesso, vbNullString)
            .ExportAsFixedFormat CurPath & rs!Acquirente & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF, False, wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen
            .Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
            
        ' in the ExportAsFixedFormat here above called one of the SQL query values to make a unique and distinctive name. Also please note use of CurPath for portability
        
        End With
        Set wDoc = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
    Next

Leave:
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    If Not wDoc Is Nothing Then wDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
    If Not wApp Is Nothing Then wApp.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```