# how do i use access data to write an word document?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, ms-access-2007

I want to write a basic examination report on word, and than using access form complete the "fields",
for example:

the student X was doing Y during the last year.
he had difficulties at: A
and done good job at: B

than ill have a table of students in access, with name, overall observation, goos and bads.
the name has to replace the X in the word letter, the overall will replace the Y and etc.

i found some blog that explains how to  do this using word bookmarks, but for some reason, the code isn't working...

thats the code i tired (just for the name, i didn't put yet all the info,

```
Dim AddyLineVar As String

AddyLineVar = [FirstName] + " " + [LastName]

Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.application")


Dim mergedoc As String

mergedoc = Application.CurrentProject.Path
mergedoc = mergedoc + "\wow.dotx"

wrd.Documents.Add mergedoc
wrd.Visible = True
wrd.activedocument.Bookmark
wrd.Item("FIRSTNAME").range.Text = AddyLineVar
wrd.activedocument.PrintOut
wrd.activedocument.Close wddonotsavechanges
wrd.Quit
```

Comment: An Access report will not satisfy your requirements? What does "isn't working" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: What you describe would be more easily achieved using Mail Merge in Word, an approach that does not require any code.

Comment: See this, might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62392840/generating-completed-pdf-forms-using-word-docs-and-ms-access/62393395#62393395

Comment: 1) Mail merge wont help because im making it for someone who has no knowlege in computers and it will take him too much time to do this over and over again. 2) doenst working means it shows an error (438) that object doesnt support the Bookmark

Comment: 3) About the code of Kostas K. i tried it, and it shows me  a compile error "user defined type not defined" to the line: "Dim wApp As Word.Application"

Comment: In Kostas K.'s code, change `Dim wApp As Word.Application` to `Dim wApp`, and `Dim wDoc As Word.Document` also change to `Dim wDoc`, and later change `Set wApp = New Word.Application` to `Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`.

Comment: thanks! now its working, but it changes only the first bookmark, if i have 5 times the same bookmark, it doesnt change it all the times, how do i make it to change all?